# Android Problem: EditText, KeyListener and the physical Back Button

Tags: android, keylistener, android-softkeyboard, android-edittext

My activity implements KeyListener and my edittext has a key listener set.

```
editor = new EditText(this);
        editor.setMinLines(4);
        editor.setMinimumWidth(400);
        editor.setKeyListener(this);
```

WHen the user types something and presses "enter" on the softkeyboard a textview's text is set to the users input.

```
@Override
public int getInputType() {

    return InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE;
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
        KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

        outview.setText(editor.getText());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here outview is a TextView. My problem is that in this activity the physical back button doesn't work. Press it and nothing happens. ANy advice would be welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By returning `true` from the `onKeyDown` function, you are informing Android that you have handled all key events.  Instead, only return true in the case of the enter key.  Return `false` otherwise.  This will allow Android to handle the back button key press.

Answer (score 0):

> find enter of softkeyboard

```
txt.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
        {
                  outview.setText(editor.getText());
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```